# groups accociated with user in ITIM

Tags: java, tivoli-identity-manager

I am working in JAVA application and authenticating user through ITIM api. How to get groups accociated with user through ITIM api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system user will have an attribute of ‘erroles’ through which we can get information of user groups/Roles.

Get **DistinguishedName** from **Person** object.
Make **PersonMO** object having constructor like `new PersonMO(platform, subject, person.getDistinguishedName());`

Make `new AccountManager(platform, subject);`

This will give accounts collection `accountManager.getAccounts(personMO, LocaleCreator.getLocale());`

Get **getSystemUserDN(userId);**. **PersonDao** class will help in getting this.

Make **new SystemUserMO(m_platform, m_subject, new DistinguishedName(systemUserDN));**

Get the roles/Groups from **systemUserMO.getData().getRoles()**

Cheers
Imran Tariq